# The type 'ChangeNotifierProxyProvider' is declared with 2 type parameters, but 3 type arguments were given

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a provider inside of another provider using that declaration

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Sali>(
            update: (ctx, auth, prevData) => Sali(
                auth.token, auth.userId, prevData == null ? [] : prevData.sali),
          ),
```

but I need to use 2 providers inside another so I tried:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth,Mese, Sali>(
            update: (ctx, auth,mes, prevData) => Sali(
                auth.token, auth.userId, prevData == null ? [] : prevData.sali),
```

but got this error:

> "The type 'ChangeNotifierProxyProvider' is declared with 2 type
>   parameters, but 3 type arguments were given.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mrapi, I haven't used `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` but have you tried [ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2.html). Looking at the documentation, i think it takes 3 parameters.